# Ruby on Rails 3rd edition - chapter 3 exercise 3.6.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby on rails and learning it through Ruby on rails 3rd edition online version . In the exercise 3.6.2 where it requires to add a contact page in the sample_app , Iam running through test failures which i am unable to figure out .The failure message is as follows -

```
   1) Failure:
    StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:13]:
  <Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was 
  <Help | Ruby on Rails tutorial Sample App>..
  Expected 0 to be >= 1.
   2) Failure:
   StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contact [/home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:23]:
   <Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App> expected but was
   <Contact | Ruby on Rails tutorial Sample App>..
   Expected 0 to be >= 1.
```

The route.rb file is as follows -

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

root 'static_pages#home'
get 'static_pages/help'
get 'static_pages/about'
get 'static_pages/contact'

end
```

The test file static_pages_controller.rb  is as follows -

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   test "should get home" do
     get :home
     assert_response :success
     assert_select "title" , "Home | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
 end

   test "should get help" do
      get :help
      assert_response :success
      assert_select "title" , "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end
   test "should get about" do
      get :about
      assert_response :success
      assert_select "title" , "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
end
   test "should get contact" do
      get :contact
      assert_response :success
      assert_select "title" , "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
 end
end
```

The application file application.html.erb is -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
     <title> <%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails tutorial Sample App</title>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 </head>
  <body>

   <%= yield %>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Also I am doin it inside a branch -

> ~/workspace/sample_app (static-pages-exercise)

and not in master .

The code is accessing the page and it works if I check it via Browser of my cloud ide.

Plz throw some light and Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its especially noticeable when StackOverflow's code highlighter illuminates the syntax in the error message you pasted; the problem is your title has a slightly different case:

The test is looking for

```
Ruby on Rails **Tutorial** Sample App
```

But you spelled "tutorial" with a lower case T in the `<title>` tag:

```
<title> <%= yield(:title) %> | Ruby on Rails **tutorial** Sample App</title>
```

(Asterisks mine)

Change `tutorial` to `Tutorial` and your tests should pass.

Comment: Thanks a ton !... man I wasted so many hours overlooking a silly mistake on my part . Thanks for helping .